# Windows 10, Set-NetConnectionProfile with Index changes all Networks

Tags: windows, powershell

In Windows 10 64bit I use the command **Set-NetConnection Profile -InterfaceIndex 30 -NetworkCategory Private** in the Powershell and it changes all network connections which had the same profile as the interface with index 30.

My Question: Why does this command change all networks?

They are all virtual networks, but I tried the same on another PC with two physical adapters and the same thing happens.

[networks before change](https://i.stack.imgur.com/omIFw.png)

[the command I am entering](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0i6qC.png)

networks after change : i.stack.imgur.com/WW4Iy.png

I found technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj899565.aspx (sorry reputation) and it says **The Set-NetConnectionProfile cmdlet changes the network category setting of a connection profile. A connection profile represents a network connection.**

Could it be that a connection profile is representating more than one network connection?

**Edit:**

They are all not identified Networks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you change something for unindentified networks, because these networks are unindentified, they are not given a connection profile, this means any change is applied to all unidentified networks.

What you need to do is to make them identified. Identification relies on having a gateway address. One trick is to add a second IP to the interface, usually just 1 before the broadcast address for the subnet, and then assign that address as the gateway. This makes Windows automatically identify the network (using your own machine's characteristics), and then allow you to set a firewall profiles to it, and other details.

I have created a powershell script that makes this easy: https://gist.github.com/CMCDragonkai/dbd2d94840cdaf79d3f6964bbd58e92f

Try it!